# How do you install PyMongo for Python 3.3?

Tags: python, pymongo, python-3.3

I downloaded the package/project source from here for Windows: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymongo/

I don't quite understand how to install this, as I'm not sure what tools they're using or if they're using command prompt.

My Python33 folder is located in my C drive, if that helps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongo is a separate program from python all together. So, when you're trying to run PyMongo you first have to go through the steps of setting up your MongoDB (mongod.exe in Mongo folder); they also supply a mongo console and other tools you can use.

To verify pymongo was installed you need to just `import pymongo` from IDLE or the command line; if it works then it's installed, if it fails you installed incorrectly.

Once it's installed correctly you connect your python script, using pymongo, to the locally run database (separate program) and query from there.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client.ndsearch # table name
... etc ...
```

Goodluck!

Comment: But the thing is that I installed it correctly on my computer without error. Yet, trying to use the command "import pymongo" states: "ImportError: No module named 'pymongo'". I don't quite get where you're trying to head with this.

Comment: But I followed to the letter every instruction on this page. I don't understand where I could have screwed up. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/